# how do I punctuate this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should this discussion result in a definite need for additional funding I will submit a request for additional dollars at that time.

Answer (score 2):

I would punctuate it like this:

> Should this discussion result in a definite need for additional funding, I will submit a request for additional dollars at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Should this discussion result in a definite need for additional funding, I will subsequently submit a request for additional funds.